# Jsfiddle and Jquery

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mushyee/q23kV/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calculator-button").click(function(){
      window.confirm("sometext");
});
```

No response when clicking the button. I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Just run `jsHint` on it and you'll figure it out I'm sure!

Comment: I think the upvoter was applauding your choice of username :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `});` for document ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".calculator-button").click(function() {
    window.confirm("sometext");
  });
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q23kV/1/)